# ActiveMQ, find env script

Tags: java, apache, jms, activemq-classic, serializable

I was trying to send an ObjectMessage containing a myObject, instance of myClass, using ActiveMQ as JMS Provider.

Than an error occurred in the receiving application, saying:

```
Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available   
to  broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class    
client.MyClass! This class is not trusted to be serialized as   
ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org
/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted 
classes.
```

I read the page and it says:

```
 If you need to exchange object messages, you need to add packages your 
 applications are using. You can do that with by using 
 org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES system property of the 
 broker. You can add this system property to ACTIVEMQ_OPTS variable in 
 ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/bin/env script.
```

I am using ActiveMQ launching it from a directory where I extracted the rar and using the command prompt to launch it. In the \bin subfolder, there is no env script, only the activemq script.

Where the env script is?